# Binomial GLM in Julia - how to specify hits and misses

Tags: julia, glm

In Julia, I'd like to calculate a GLM with family `Binomial()` and `LogitLink()`. My data are three linear arays: `xvalues`, number of `hits`, and number of `misses`. I would like to explain the binomially distributed hits and misses by their positions on the x axis. I have multiple samples with the same x coordinates (because the data originally stems from a 2D array that was flattened).

In R, I have to supply hits and misses in a two-column-matrix. Something like the following works:

`glm1 <- glm(cbind(hits, misses)~xvalues, family=binomial)`

But in the GLM formula in Julia, I cannot specify arbitrary arrays. Rather, I have to specify columns from a dataframe and dataframe columns cannot be 2D it seems. So I've put my data into a dataframe:

`data = DataFrame(xvals = xvals, hits = hits, misses = misses)`

and tried things that don't work (like this):

`glm1 = glm(hcat(hits, misses) ~ xvals, data, family = Binomial, link = LogitLink())`

An example with data can be downloaded [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hannesbecher/hannesbecher.github.io/master/misc/glm.jl).

Any advice?
Cheers,
Hannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it isn't pretty to inflate the dataset into a ~100k row dataframe, it does get it to work. To use the code below, first load your dataset into `xvals`,`hits` and `misses` (as linked in the question) and then:

```
# spreading dataset to one row per trial...   
data = DataFrame(
    xvals = vcat(rep(xvals,hits),rep(xvals,misses)), 
    outcome = vcat(rep(1,sum(hits)),rep(0,sum(misses))))

glm1 = glm(outcome ~ xvals, data, Binomial(),LogitLink())
```

The results seem to fit the data by my cursory glance. Also note the `Binomial` and `LogicLink` are positional parameters and not named parameters.

Comment: Cool, works. Still I'd be happy about something more elegant. But maybe the elegance has yet to be implemented...